# Font Substitution - How Does It Work?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts

Let's say I open Outlook and compose an email and choose a totally random font and hit send.

Let's assume I have Outlook set to send in HTML format, and my mail server sends HTML and the recipients server receives HTML, and their client displays HTML etc.

However, let's assume their PC doesn't have the font I chose installed (could be Windows, Mac, Linux, anything).

What happens next with regards to how it chooses a font to display the message?

Comment: I believe it's dependent on how the rendering engine is configured and with what default font.  For Outlook, I believe it uses IE as it's rendering engine, but I'm not positive if that's still the case.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution

Look at the links provided at the bottom for GNOME and Mozilla. See here:

- http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/metrical-equivalent-fonts-and-font.html

for OpenOffice. Here's an extensive list of links about the topic:

- http://www.allgraphicdesign.com/downloadfonts/fontsarticles/fontsubstitutionstipshelp.html

Basically, the answer to your question is - however the target application wants to do it...